# sql query to get unique id for a row in oracle based on its continuity

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem that needs to be solved using sql in oracle.

I have a dataset like given below:

```
value | date
------------- 
1 | 01/01/2017 
2 | 02/01/2017 
3 | 03/01/2017 
3 | 04/01/2017
2 | 05/01/2017 
2 | 06/01/2017 
4 | 07/01/2017 
5 | 08/01/2017
```

I need to show the result in the below format:

```
value    | date     |   Group
1   |   01/01/2017  |   1
2   |   02/01/2017  |   2
3   |   03/01/2017  |   3
3   |   04/01/2017  |   3
2   |   05/01/2017  |   4
2   |   06/01/2017  |   4
4   |   07/01/2017  |   5
5   |   08/01/2017  |   6
```

The logic is whenever `value` changes over `date`, it gets assigned a new `group/id`, but if its the same as the previous one , then its part of the same `group`.

Comment: What is the logic that transforms what you to what you want?

Comment: The logic is whenever  value changes over date it gets assigned a new group/id , but if its the same as the previous one , then its part of the same group. Hope this helps.

Comment: Amit - what you have in the Comment should actually be added to your post. I did that for you this time, but please remember that for the future - any further clarification of requirements, input, or output, and additional code you provide etc. should go in the body of your post; use the Comments just to alert others that you edited the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method using `lag()` and cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when value = prev_value then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (order by date) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t;
```

The logic here is to simply count the number of times that the value changes from one month to the next.

This assumes that `date` is actually stored as a date and not a string.  If it is a string, then the ordering will not be correct.  Either convert to a date or use a column that specifies the correct ordering.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause, introduced in Oracle 12.*

```
select value, dt, mn as grp
from   inputs
match_recognize (
  order by dt
  measures match_number() as mn
  all rows per match
  pattern  ( a b* )
  define   b as value = prev(value)
)
order by dt   --  if needed
;
```

Here is how this works: Other than SELECT, FROM and ORDER BY, the query has only one clause, MATCH_RECOGNIZE. What this clause does is: it takes the rows from `inputs` and it orders them by `dt`. Then it searches for patterns: one row, marked as `a`, with no constraints, followed by zero or more rows `b`, where `b` is defined by the condition that the `value` is the same as for the prev[ious] row. What the clause calculates or `measures` is the `match_number()` - first "match" of the pattern, second match etc. We use this match number as the group number (`grp`) in the outer query - that's all we needed!

***Notes**: The existence of solutions like this shows why it is important for posters to state their Oracle version. (Run the statement `select * from v$version` to find out.) Also: `date` and `group` are reserved words in Oracle and shouldn't be used as column names. Not even for posting made-up sample data. (There are workarounds but they aren't needed in this case.) Also, whenever using dates like 03/01/2017 in a post, please indicate whether that is March 1 or January 3, there's no way for "us" to tell. (It wasn't important in this case, but it is in the vast majority of cases.)